# Error using PST(Place Syntax Tool) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, syntaxerror

I'm working with the PST(Place Syntax Tool) that I want to create segment map (Geometry is LineString) in QGIS.

I'm having the problems with these errors below

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

Exception: QGISModel: Column '' not found! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenyuru/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/pst/ui/pages/progresspage.py", line 64, in start
    task.run(dlgt)
  File "/Users/chenyuru/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/pst/analyses/createsegmentmapanalysis.py", line 74, in run
    extra_column_type = model.columnType(props['in_network'], copy_column_name)
  File "/Users/chenyuru/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/pst/model/model.py", line 67, in columnType
    field = layer.fields()[self._safeFieldIndex(layer, column)]
  File "/Users/chenyuru/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/pst/model/model.py", line 338, in _safeFieldIndex
    raise Exception("QGISModel: Column '%s' not found!" % name)
Exception: QGISModel: Column '' not found!
```